# Can we reset the window.performance javascript object?

Tags: javascript, performance, window-object

I am working on a Single Page Application and I am interested to know about the performance of my application. So I decided to go with **window.performance.timing**. But, as I am working on SPA this data can't be reset for every DOM change. So is there any way so that I can reset this object. If not, how can I calculate my performance?

Thanks in advance